# Converting to long and validate

Tags: validation, jsf, converters, long-integer

I have a Facelets page with a form with ICEfaces components. `empId` is a long type property,  which has to be checked if null or not in the bean. It is taken as `String` in the form, and I am converting that to long type using `Long.valueof(empId).longValue();` in order to pass it to DAO to check against DB column.

Is this the way we are supposed to do it? Or are there another ways?

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to use a `Long` property instead of a `String` property to enforce automatic conversion to `Long` by JSF/EL (it has namely builtin conversion for standard `Number`, `Boolean` and `Enum` types).

```
private Long empId;
```

with

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.empId}" />
```

You'd like to use `required` attribute to validate required input.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.empId}" required="true" />
```

Any conversion or validation error message can be shown using `<h:message>`.

```
<h:inputText id="empId" value="#{bean.empId}" required="true" />
<h:message for="empId" />
```

You can if necessary change the conversion and required message as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="empId" value="#{bean.empId}" required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Please enter employee ID." 
    converterMessage="Please enter digits only." />
<h:message for="empId" />
```

This way you don't need to perform any conversion/validation in the bean's action method, which would be the wrong place for it anyway. You should use JSF builtin converters or a custom `Converter` for conversion and JSF builtin validators or a custom `Validator` for validation. The backing bean property should hold the right type already and the backing bean action method should not do any conversion/validation.

I only wonder if that DAO method call to check the column can't better be handled by a custom `Validator`, but that depends all on the concrete functional requirement which is unclear from the question.